# OneToMany SQL Relationships

Tags: java, jpa, kotlin, one-to-many

I want to have a `OneToMany` relationship with SQL, and a `ManyToOne` relationship. I have a Ticket entity, and a TeamMember entity. However, when I first save the Ticket entity, I will not know the TeamMember, and if I set it to null I get this:

```
2020-05-29 23:49:55.754  
ERROR 24020 --- [onPool-worker-2]  o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:  
Column 'team_member_id' cannot be null
```

What should I do?

Ticket:

```kotlin
data class Ticket(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id:Long = 0,
    val ticketId:String,
    var price:Int? = null,
    val openDate:LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(),
    var closeDate:LocalDateTime? = null,
    var paypalId:String? = null,
    var paid:Boolean = false,
    var status:TicketStatus = TicketStatus.OPEN,
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_member_id", nullable = false)
    val teamMember: TeamMember? = null,
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
    val customer:Customer
)
```

TeamMember:

```kotlin
@Entity
data class TeamMember(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id:Long = 0,
    val discordId:String,
    val joinDate:LocalDateTime,
    val ordersCompleted:Int,
    val amountMade:Int,
    val email:String,
    val pastWork:String,
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "teamMember", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL],
            orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    val tickets:Set<Ticket> = setOf()
)
```

Comment: Can you show your code? Especially the code with the `teamMember` and the code filling it.

Comment: edited my message

Answer (score 0):

Look at this part of your code (of `Ticket`):

```kotlin
@JoinColumn(name = "team_member_id", nullable = false)
val teamMember: TeamMember? = null
```

You set the SQL column to be non-`null` using `nullable=false`.

However, you declared the attribute as `TeamMember?` and you set it to `null`.

You can either set `teamMember` to something that is not `null` before persisting it or set `nullable` to `true` (depending on what you need).